# ArangoDB Retrieve parent object based on multiple filters on children properties

Tags: arangodb

I have a Person object as follows

```
 {
   name: 'John Doe'
   properties: 
      [
         {
            name: 'eyeColor', 
            value: 'brown'
         },
         {
            name: 'age', 
            value: 25
         },
         {
            name: 'interest', 
            value: 'reading'
         },
         {
            name: 'interest', 
            value: 'diving'
         }
      ]
 }
```

Now I want to be able to filter my object based on multiple properties. In pseudocode:

```
Return all people for which 
 
there exists any p.property such that 
 p.property.propertyname == 'interest'
 AND p.property.propertyvalue == 'reading'

AND there exists any p.property such that
 p.property.propertyname == 'age'
 AND p.property.propertyvalue < 30
```

What is the most concise and extensible (I want to be able to apply N of these filters) of doing this without having too many intermediate results?

Comment: Are you stuck with this data-format, or is it in your hand to change it?  This kind of data-design is seldom necessary - you gain nothing in flexibility in a scenario using json as data-interchange format, and loose (as your question shows) almost all easy ways for meaningful evaluation and manipulation.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by data-interchange format? What other way would you suggest that this data is designed in a json database? @TomRegner

Comment: arangodb-documents are in principle json documents (not really, but equivalent and compatible). If you don't abstract the properties away, and just use `{name: "NAME", interests: ["reading", "diving"], eyeColor: "blue", age: 25}`, you can filter easily -- if you need a certain automation I suggest using a json-schema definition - you can use it to build filters automatically, validate data passed in via API, validate on a database level (>3.7).

Comment: You can be as strict and loose as you like/need and each document is easy to understand, filter and use.

Comment: What I've left out in the question for my specific use case is an expiry date for each property, i.e. 01-01-2100 if unexpired or some timestamp in history if expired. As you've already kind of guessed, there is some generalisation that I'm hoping to achieve. In addition I want only unexpired entries. Could you explain a bit more how exactly you would go about the schema definition and how that fits with automatic filter building ?

Comment: Just to add for my specific use case again: this "property" is actually an integral part of the domain and is something that is highly variable in naming. The programmer isn't aware of what kind of properties a "Person" could possibly have beforehand

Comment: Hmm - if the data-structure is as highly volatile/completly unspecified as this, another aproach would be to have the properties as seperate collection, use an edge collection to associate the properties with the person and use the graph query part of AQL to filter.